# Unable to access Controller action after sign in and adding Authorize attribute to the Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I've set up a simple login page to login my user when he clicks the login button. The user gets assigned roles upon the login. To test if it works out I've done the following code for login:

```
  [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Login")]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string userName = model.Username;
                string[] userRoles = new string[5];
                userRoles[0] = "Administrator";

                ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userName));

              //  userRoles.ToList().ForEach((role) => identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRoles[0]));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName));

                AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity);

                return RedirectToAction("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Login",model);
            }
        }
```

And I've added a Authorize attribute to my MVC action, just to see if the user will really be able to access it after the login... Here's how I've done it:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrator")]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            var model = new UserRegistrationViewModel();
            var countries = Connection.ctx.Countries.OrderBy(x => x.CountryName).ToList();
            model.Countries = new SelectList(countries, "CountryId", "CountryName");
            return View(model);
        }
```

But for some reason when I try to access like following:

```
mywebsite.com/user/register
```

It shows me:

```
HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
```

What could it be ?

Edit:

Here is the snapshot of claims and identities after the user logs in:

[image]

And 2nd one:

[image]

Comment: Anyone has any ideas guys ? :/

Comment: `identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"));` Could you hard code `Administrator` and debug again? Could you show ***Authorize*** attribute used in ***UserController***?

Comment: Okay one moment I will try that.

Comment: What you are saying with [Authorize(Roles="Administrator")] is that this action cannot be accesible by others users that not have the "Administrator" role

Comment: @Win I tried, its the same thing... 

jcvegan, yes, this what I'm testing out essentially... As you can see from the code above the user gets role "Administrator" upon login... So I should be able to access the action without any problem, but it says that I have no permission even after the login...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you ensure that you have Cookie middleware? For example,

### Startup.cs

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(YourApplicationName.Startup))]
namespace YourApplicationName
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });
        }
    }
}
```

[Using Cookie Middleware without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html)

Comment: I only have map.SignalR(); in my Configuration function in startup class... Ill try this one :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you are getting the 401 because your user does not have the "Administrator" role. Check your user (identity) on the subsequent request(s), I am not sure that the Roles persist in the cookie - you may need to find a way to persist the roles yourself.

Comment: I've included the snapshots after the login... Can you look into it ? :)